# Can I make type aliases for type constructors in python using the typing module?

Tags: python

Since python version 3.5, you can use type hints to indicate what type of arguments a function is expecting. I find these type hints extremely valuable for documentation purposes, so I try to use them as much as I can. They also help the linter and therefore regularly save me from bugs introduced by code changes.

For example, in my code I have a few functions which take a zero-argument function as an argument. E.g.:

```
def onReady(f: Callable[[], Any]) -> None:
    ...
```

Or

```
def checkIfReady(f: Callable[[], Bool]) -> None:
    ...
```

What I would like to do is make a type alias like so (the code below is not valid python):

```
Action[A] = Callable[[], A]
```

And then I could shorten my types for the arguments above:

```
def onReady(f: Action[Any]) -> None:
    ...
```

I know I can make a type alias for a specific instance, e.g.:

```
ActionBool = Callable[[], bool]
```

And I know of the existance of `NewType` in the `typing` module, but neither of these seem to generalize to higher order types.

Comment: Do you have an action class? if you derive every action you have from this class you can have this king of typing. The class should be `class Action(Generic[T]): ` with `T = TypeVar('T')`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think i've found the simplest solution. According to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases), this is valid:

```
T = TypeVar('T') #  or TypeVar('T', int, float, bool, str)
Action = Callable[[], T]
def onReady(f: Action[Any]) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: With this I can indeed write: `onReady(f: Action[bool]): ...`, however, as with the answer of Aran-Fey, it does not actually make `mypy` understand what is going on. E.g. `foo = onReady(lambda: 3)` does not give a type warning. Even `foo = onReady("not even a function")` does not give a type warning.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer I can't reproduce that. `onReady(lambda: 3)` _shouldn't_ show a type warning, because `lambda: 3` is indeed a `Callable[[], Any]`. Passing in a string, on the other hand, correctly gives me a `Argument 1 to "onReady" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Callable[[], Any]"` warning. (Using mypy)

Comment: Hmm, let me double check

Comment: Are you using mypy directly? I'm relying on pycharms static type checker, that might be the difference.

Comment: Ok, I just tested with mypy from the CLI and you are right. Then it seems like the issue is pycharm related, and your answer is correct.