# Use generic in type alias

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, typing

My type annotations I currently have look similar to the following, and I want to use an [typing alias](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases) to not repeat myself so much:

A class has class variables, which can be either:

- some specified type, or
- a function (with a parameter) returning that *same* type.

```py
class Foo(object):
  state:  ClassVar[Union[str, Callable[[SomeObject], str]]]  # str or func->str
  number: ClassVar[Union[int, Callable[[SomeObject], int]]]  # int or func->int
  foobar: ClassVar[Union[bool, Callable[[SomeObject], bool]]] # bool or func->bool
# end class
```

For completion sake, here is an example implementation:

```py
class FooBar(Foo):
   state = "something"
   number = lambda x: int(x.bla)
   
   @classmethod
   def foobar(cls, x):
     return x.blabla == cls.state
   # end def
# end class
```

However I can't figure out how to make a subscriptable generic. I'm seeking for something kinda like:

```py
ClassValueOrCallable = lambda T: ClassVar[Union[T, Callable[[SomeObject], T]]]

class Foo(object):
  state:  ClassValueOrCallable(str)
  number: ClassValueOrCallable(int)
  foobar: ClassValueOrCallable(bool)
```

---

**Edit:**
Following [mypy's generic type aliases section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-type-aliases), it seems to should be possible to write it as

```py
T = TypeVar('T')  # Any type.
ClassValueOrCallable = ClassVar[Union[T, Callable[[SomeObject], T]]]

class Foo(object):
  state:  ClassValueOrCallable[str]
  number: ClassValueOrCallable[int]
  foobar: ClassValueOrCallable[bool]
```

But at least PyCharm doesn't recognise that, and just displays the type as `Any`, so I'm not too sure if it is correct.
[image: pycharm quick-docs showing 'Any']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make type aliases for type constructors in python using the typing module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887430/can-i-make-type-aliases-for-type-constructors-in-python-using-the-typing-module)

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```py
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')  # Any type.
ValueOrCallable = Union[T, Callable[..., T]]

class Foo(object):
  state:  ClassVar[ValueOrCallable]
```

Comment: Pycharm agrees :)

Comment: But I can't seem to supply the `str` type hint, etc.